# How to realise nested RepeatIn in RML

Tags: odoo, rml

I am creating reports in OpenERP. And I work with RML.

But now I am blocked and I need to work with nested repeatIn. I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<section>
<blockTable colwidths="150,100,100,100,100,100" style="Table1">
<tr>
<td>
      <para style="P8">NOM EMPLOYÉ</para>
    </td>
    <td>

      <para style="P7">[[ repeatIn(repeatIn(get_employee_lines(example.company_id,example.date_start,example.date_end), 'p'),'o') ]]</para>
      <para style="P7">[[ o ]]</para>
    </td>      
  </tr>
</blockTable>
```

I got this error:

```
 2015-09-09 10:54:39,165 6414 ERROR openerp openerp.tools.safe_eval:      Cannot eval "o[ p['name'] ]"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 288, in safe_eval
 return eval(test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode), globals_dict, locals_dict)
 File "", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'p' is not defined
 2015-09-09 10:54:39,166 6414 ERROR openerp openerp.tools.safe_eval: Cannot eval "o[ p['name'] ]"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 288, in safe_eval
return eval(test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode), globals_dict, locals_dict)
 File "", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'p' is not defined
 2015-09-09 10:54:39,166 6414 ERROR openerp openerp.tools.safe_eval: Cannot eval "o[ p['name'] ]"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 288, in safe_eval
return eval(test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode), globals_dict, locals_dict)
 File "", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'p' is not defined
```

I don't know how and I didn't find any example.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have got the answer :)

Here is the RML code:

```
<section>
<blockTable colwidths="150,100,100,100,100,100" style="Table1">
<tr>
<td>
      <para style="P8">NOM EMPLOYÉ</para>
    </td>
    <td>
      <para style="P8">MATRICULE</para>
    </td>
    <td>

      <para style="P7">[[ repeatIn(repeatIn(get_employee_lines(example.company_id,example.date_start,example.date_end), 'p', 'td'),'o') ]]</para>
      <para style="P7">[[ repeatIn(o['p'], 'line', 'td') ]]</para>
      <para style="P7">[[ line['name'] ]]</para>
      <para style="P7">[[ line['matricule'] ]]</para>
    </td>      
  </tr>
</blockTable>
```

Best Regards.